# pyfacebook @facebook.require_login() decorator causing constant auth_token refresh

Tags: django, facebook, pyfacebook

First time using pyFacebook. I've literally copied the [example application](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tree/master/examples/fbsample) and put it up onto my server. I've created an FB app and now when I try to load the app basically what happens is that the browser keeps refreshing. I noticed in the url (for example)

> https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?auth_token=8f826cae31717068c18fb16fd7f0a758

Keeps refreshing with the auth_token changing. If I remove the `@facebook.require_login()` decorator then the page displays without a problem.

Help please.

---

I've just noticed that it only does this when I select *IFrame* and not *FBML* within my app settings. I have fbml templates which don't work. I know have normal html templates which work on the website but when I select IFrame I get that constant loop (changing url with blank white screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after weeks of pain the problem I was having was that Facebook updated it's entire API. This broke python based apps that were based on that. Like PyFacebook.

I now use [fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango-example) and this it's new, has a great developer and nice documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably somewhere in facebook/**init**.py, around line 1742

```
    if not params:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            params = self.validate_signature(request.POST)
        if not params:   #was else
```

iframe makes POST call, but auth_token is GET variable.. though if validate_signature fails (params still None) go to GET validation. Also I commented out the return in auth_token checks as suggested in pyfacebook issue tracker.

Comment: Problem with this is that the call to `self.auth.getSession()` still fails, a couple lines later.